# C# method to retrieve a Work time slots based on few parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, methods, scheduling

Could someone help me write a method in c# that would accept following parameters and provide a list of working times.

1.String workStartingTime

2.String workStopTime

3.int iBreaktime

4.int iWorkInterval

I did write a code that works but damn it's too un-maintainable and contrived. Sample output for executing with below parameter is provided :

`workStartTime = "9:00 AM"`,

`workStopTime = "6:00 PM"`,

`ibreakTime = 10`,

`iWorkInterval = 60`

**Output:**

`9:00 AM - 10:00 AM`

`10:10 AM - 11:10 AM`

`11:20 AM - 12:20 PM`

`12:30 PM - 01:30 PM`

hope you get the idea, for each interval leave a gap and span the thing until work ending time.

**Note:**

By the way the work starttime and endtime are stored in database like so `9:30 AM - 10:00 PM` or `9:00 - 16:00` ie 12 or 24 Hour format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **CalendarPeriodCollector** of the free [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/TimePeriod.aspx).

The tool supports various filters, including working hours:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
public void CalendarPeriodCollectorSample()
{
  CalendarPeriodCollectorFilter filter = new CalendarPeriodCollectorFilter();
  filter.Months.Add( YearMonth.January ); // only Januaries
  filter.WeekDays.Add( DayOfWeek.Friday ); // only Fridays
  filter.CollectingHours.Add( new HourRange( 8, 18 ) ); // working hours

  CalendarTimeRange testPeriod =
    new CalendarTimeRange( new DateTime( 2010, 1, 1 ), new DateTime( 2011, 12, 31 ) );
  Console.WriteLine( "Calendar period collector of period: " + testPeriod );
  // > Calendar period collector of period:
  //            01.01.2010 00:00:00 - 30.12.2011 23:59:59 | 728.23:59

  CalendarPeriodCollector collector =
          new CalendarPeriodCollector( filter, testPeriod );
  collector.CollectHours();
  foreach ( ITimePeriod period in collector.Periods )
  {
    Console.WriteLine( "Period: " + period );
  }
  // > Period: 01.01.2010; 08:00 - 17:59 | 0.09:59
  // > Period: 08.01.2010; 08:00 - 17:59 | 0.09:59
  // > Period: 15.01.2010; 08:00 - 17:59 | 0.09:59
  // > Period: 22.01.2010; 08:00 - 17:59 | 0.09:59
  // > Period: 29.01.2010; 08:00 - 17:59 | 0.09:59
  // > Period: 07.01.2011; 08:00 - 17:59 | 0.09:59
  // > Period: 14.01.2011; 08:00 - 17:59 | 0.09:59
  // > Period: 21.01.2011; 08:00 - 17:59 | 0.09:59
  // > Period: 28.01.2011; 08:00 - 17:59 | 0.09:59
} // CalendarPeriodCollectorSample
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void CreateTimes(DateTime start, DateTime end, int interval, TimeSpan work)
{
    DateTime currentStart = start;
    while(currentStart < end && currentStart.Add(work)<end)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - {1}", currentStart, currentStart.Add(work)));
        currentStart.AddMinutes(interval);
    }
}
```

Comment: How could you convert `9:30 AM - 6:00Pm` string to separate date time instances could you also add that code also TimeSpan could you elaborate more on how parameters converts to your method parameters

Comment: you can use the DateTime.Parse mathod: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx

Comment: I suppose `DateTime.Parse("(9:00 AM - 6:00 PM")` would yield a expection invalid string

Comment: Well, use "9:00 AM - 6:00 PM".Split("-")[0].Trim() and "9:00 AM - 6:00 PM".Split("-")[1].Trim()

Comment: Perhaps you should start with some c# basics first. Have a look at all build in types and what they offer.

Comment: sad thing is `DateTime.Parse("9:30 AM")` would also lead to exception

Comment: @Deeptechtons - `DateTime.Parse("9:30 AM")` works on my machine.. because it contains `AM` you might need to specify a CultureInfo: `DateTime.Parse("9:30AM", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))`